# Celery not working when running in Docker container

Tags: django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to develop an application which is composed of a listener which sends events to RabbitMQ, which Celery extracts from a queue.

When running all the components locally my application works as expected. It also works if my listener is running locally, and all the other components are running in Docker containers. But if I also run my listener in a container then Celery does not receive any events.

The application is based on Django and the connection to Celery is done like this:

```
app = Celery('mini_iot')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And in settings.py I have:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rabbitmq'
```

Where rabbitmq is the hostname of the container.

The listener sends tasks to Celery using the `delay` function.

The docker-compose is:

```
version: '3'
services:
 listener:
  image: core-app 
  command: python manage.py runscript listener
  volumes:
   - .:/mini-iot
  depends_on:
   - rabbitmq
   - mqtt
  working_dir: /mini-iot/mini_iot
 worker:
  image: core-app 
  command: celery -A mini_iot worker --loglevel=info -f log2.txt
  volumes:
   - .:/mini-iot
  depends_on:
   - rabbitmq
   - mqtt
  working_dir: /mini-iot/mini_iot
 rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.6.10
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  ports:
   - "5672:5672"
   - "15672:15672"
```

Can anyone help me debug the problem or does anyone have an idea about what the problem is?

The containers can communicate with each other on the correct ports. I have tested using telnet.

Comment: The description of the docker setup is necessary, so people can help. Stuff like the network configuration of the containers is essential for this case.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question

Comment: Any error messages ?

Comment: No error message appears

Comment: @Alexandra Would you happen to know, all this time later, what the solution to this Celery issue was? I seem to be experiencing the same issue, albeit I am using a SQS queue as a broker.

Answer (score 1):

I think your CELERY_BROKER_URL should be

`amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672`

According the the rabbitmq docker docs (https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/), the default username and password are guest/guest.

Answer (score 0):

you should add [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) to both `listener` & `worker`:

```
version: '3'
services:
 listener:
  image: core-app 
  command: python manage.py runscript listener
  volumes:
   - .:/mini-iot
  links:
   - rabbitmq
  depends_on:
   - rabbitmq
   - mqtt
  working_dir: /mini-iot/mini_iot
 worker:
  image: core-app 
  command: celery -A mini_iot worker --loglevel=info -f log2.txt
  volumes:
   - .:/mini-iot
  links:
   - rabbitmq
  depends_on:
   - rabbitmq
   - mqtt
  working_dir: /mini-iot/mini_iot
 rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.6.10
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  ports:
   - "5672:5672"
   - "15672:15672"
```